# smooth scrolling UITableView iPhone, with images

Tags: iphone, image, url, uitableview, nsmutabledictionary

EDIT:
after reading the answers below and looking at all the guides i am now lost, i am too noob to figure it out.

i don't want the coding done for me, i need some clear cut advice on how to set up a seperate thread and then reference it to my tableView.

Any tutorials for a NOOB?!?

---

this is the code i have set up for putting images into my tableView. All the images load but only when scrolling through the table.

How can this be stopped?

Any help would be appreciated.

```
NSString *userImage = [(Tweet*)[profile objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]  profileImage];
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(0, 0), ^{
            NSData* imageData = [[NSData alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[(Tweet*)[profile objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]  profileImage]]];          
            dict =[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
                //UIImage *retImage =[dict  objectForKey:(@"%@", userImage)];
                UIImage *retImage =[dict  objectForKey:userImage];
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                        if (!retImage) {
                        UIImage *profileImage=[UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
                        [dict setObject:profileImage forKey:userImage];
        }
                    UIImage *retImage2 =[dict  objectForKey:userImage];
                    photo.image = retImage2;


                        [imageData release];
                        });
```

Comment: You are asking a table-view specific question but you are not showing the code you are using for populating/creating the cells -  in most cases, poor setup of the UITableViewCells is the reason for slow scrolling (e.g. using transparencies). You should quote the code for tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath as that will most likely be a key-factor.

Comment: When I'm on my computer I'll copy it across

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Loading the images on a background thread is one option. The better alternative would be to use NSOperationQueue that autmagically handles the background threads.

Apple has provided a sample for the same.

Please have a look at [Lazy Loading Of TableViewCells](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/samplecode/LazyTableImages/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40009394)

I hope it helps :)

**EDIT:** If you dont know, or dont want to use threads, then there is another alternate for that. Check this out:
[downloading-images-for-table-without-threads](http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.com/2010/05/downloading-images-for-table-without.html)

Comment: Unfortunately I'm a Noob, started coding 2mths ago. The apple documentation is too confusing for me. Thanks anyway

Comment: I have provided the 'sample code link'. It might be bit complicated, but this is optimized way of doing it.

Answer (score 0):

How big are your images?  You may want to scale them down before putting them in the tableView.

something like:

```
    #define kImageSize 44 
   // Create a thumbnail version of the image for the oject.
CGSize size = newImage.size;
CGFloat ratio ;
if (size.width > size.height) {
        ratio = kImageSize / size.width;
} else {
    ratio = kImageSize/ size.height;
}
CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, ratio * size.width, ratio * size.height);

if (NULL != UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions) { //test that function is available
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(rect.size, NO, 0);  //allow iphone4 to use higher-res
} else {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rect.size);
}
[newImage drawInRect:rect];
userThumbnailImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Also, I note that every time your image is in the dictionary, you'll be storing again; you probably want to put the caching line back in the (!photo.image) clause.

Comment: Caching line, could you explain?

Comment: Couple more points now that I see the code.  I definitely agree you should be downloading in background (putting up a temporary image in the meantime).  However, I'm confused on the relationship between your first code segments and the "More code" one.  It looks like you're re-downloading the image every time in "tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath", which would be a disaster.

Comment: Finally a few minor points: your line "if (cell)" should just be "else", as you've just finished assigning those in the "then" part, so no need to do it again. And last: calling a NSString "image" is confusing; I assume you mean "imageName"

Comment: the first lot of code is under the second part, but allof the above code is under "tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath". i was calling "photo.image=[UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL: [NSURL URLWithString: userImage ]]];" without having a dictionary, so i added the nsmutabledictionary to what i already had.   so i need to figure out how to download in the background :-(

Comment: i'm thinking this might help? http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/loading-images-asynchronously-on-iphone-using-nsinvocationoperation

Comment: I like this technique better (referred to above... http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.com/2010/05/downloading-images-for-table-without.html

Comment: I see your edit at the top of the note.  I sympathize; I know how it can feel like beating your head against a while.  As a suggestion, you might check out the Stanford iPhone Application Development lectures. http://itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/viewPodcast?id=384233225     The topic of NSOperations is covered under lecture 10 in the Winter 2010, and they go through a demo with Flickr loading.

Comment: Cheers man, I'm downloading them now. I'm going away for the weekend, so I should be able to watch it and give it a go next week. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Download the images in a background thread, and when the images become available set them into the UIImageView in the table view cell.   You're stalling the main thread with loading your images over the network.

Comment: This sounds promising, but how would I go about this?

Answer (score 0):

[SOLVED]
i added an if statement, it's not optimal but it only lags if the picture doesn't exist.

```
                    if (!image) {
                    [activityIndicator startAnimating];
                        UIImage *phoneImage=[UIImage imageWithData:[[NSData alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:userImage]]];
                        NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, 
                                                                             NSUserDomainMask, YES);
                        NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
                        NSString* path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:
                                          [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@:%@", imageName, fileName]  ];
                        NSData* data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(phoneImage);
                        [data writeToFile:path atomically:YES];
                                            }               
                else{
                    photo.image=image;
                    [activityIndicator stopAnimating];
                }
```